# How would I set up kubernetes Services and pods' IP addresses and ports to send some information into a pod?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

The issue of ClusterIP, pod IP, nodePort, and targetPort are still a little confusing to me.

I want to set up a small test case to better evaluate use cases, but I am having a bit of trouble. At the moment, I am working with kubernetes for docker on mac.

What I'd like:

- A pod with an application on it that listens on a port (say, 8080).
- Pod is running on the docker-desktop node that comes with Kubernetes on Docker
- A way to send requests from my local machine to the docker-desktop node that the pod can receive on its 8080 port, and a way to get back information the pod provides in response to the request

I am pretty sure I need something like a Service to act as the middleware between the pod and me, but I am not sure how to set something like this up.

Something like the kubernetes-dashboard api, where I can access the pod with:

```
http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/#/pod?namespace=default
```

Here, know `kubernetes-dashboard` is replaced by the namespace for my pods, and `https` is replaced with whatever port name I have configured in a Service, but I am not sure about the rest.

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/expose/expose-intro/

Comment: If you want three things, please ask three questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kubernetes dashboard example that you are referring you are actually using `kubectl proxy` or `kubectl port forward` to access it. In this case Kubernetes API Server works as proxy and forwards the request to pod.

You can just create a clusterIP type service and use the `kubectl proxy` or `kubectl port forward` mechanism to access it.[Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/) is a guide on this.

The service would look like below as an example

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: MyApp
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
```

You could also use NodePort type service to expose the pod. In this case you don't need to use `kubectl proxy` or `kubectl port forward`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: MyApp
  ports:
      # By default and for convenience, the `targetPort` is set to the same value as the `port` field.
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
      # Optional field
      # By default and for convenience, the Kubernetes control plane will allocate a port from a range (default: 30000-32767)
      nodePort: 30007
```

You access it using `http://<NODEIP>:30007` where `<NODEIP>` is any of the kubernetes node's IP.

Answer (score 2):

You should define a Service with `NodePort` type to access the service from the host machine.

Follow the reference --> https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/service-access-application-cluster/